# PayPal advanced error message "Payment has been declined. Please try again"

Tags: onepage-checkout, paypal, payment

I am using PayPal advanced. Everything as far as paypal integration is concerned is working fine. Payment goes through the gateway and funds are transferred. However, when any transaction with a credit card is used, I get this pop-up error message "Payment has been declined. Please try again". I have tried everything I can find via all magento forums.

Please help! This is driving me insane.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Have you tried multiple credit cards?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1. I was not having this issue a few weeks ago. I have tried with multiple credit cards. Happens every time.

Comment: Since this is a vague paypal response, I think you should see if you can contact PayPal and see if they can find the logs and determine why it was cancelled. If you haven't changed anything in the database (API credentials), and no code was changed, that makes me doubt it is a Magento issue. Especially since you said it was working just fine a few weeks ago.

Comment: I talked to paypal and they have said that it is integrated correctly on their end and they cannot do anything further. The payment does actually go through and the funds transfer but the pop-up message comes up in the browser. Therefore, the customer tries to purchase multiple times bc they think it is not working.

Comment: I would diff your code between your code on the server (hopefully you are using version control and not blindly changing files), and a clean copy of Magento CE 1.9. See if you can see any core files that have changed. This is not normal behavior for Magento CE 1.9 so something must've been altered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Magento 2, Paypal upgraded my account to Hosted Checkout Pages and I configured Paypal Payments Advanced in Magento with layout C in Paypal.

Make sure you're not using test mode on magento when Paypal is in live mode (they need to match).

I had this issue and Paypal was trying to post to my dev.domain.com but it couldn't access it, so magento thought the order was cancelled.

since dev.domain.com was not a valid url that had been made live, Paypal could not reach it. hope this helps!